# cordova ionic error Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: cordova

I have this erreur when i execute cordova build --release android,

```html
   cordova build --release android
Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Dell\MRTv3\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Dell\MRTv3 add to body class: platform-android
 Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Dell\MRTv3\platforms\android\cordova\build
.bat --release""
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must
 fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Comment: it clearly says *Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.*  This might help [Setting Up Your Development Environment for Cordova/PhoneGap Android projects](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/setting-up-your-developmemt-environment-for-cordovaphonegap-android-projects/)

Comment: thank you Jesse, i resolved this error by deleting android platform and rebuild it